# The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. TomCat

Tags: java, scriptlet

Hi Guys I'm not new to java web edition. I have a websystem which my login page (index.jsp) runs fine. When a login is successful that's where the problem comes, i get this error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /MSS_portal_frameset.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
9:         StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
10:     
11:         while ((e = str.indexOf(pattern, s)) >= 0) {
12:             result.append(str.substring(s, e));
13:             result.append(replace);
14:             s = e+pattern.length();
15:         }

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:435)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:299)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

That section of the code is inside scriptlets <% %>.

Comment: Which java version uning your tomcat ?

Comment: Check that Tomcat's Java home or JRE home are correct. Java.lang package is one of the core system packages so failure to find it probably means misconfigured Tomcat. Also, please please don't put Java code inside a JSP! Yuk! Use servlets to process requests, and JSPs to render responses. Put all JSPs under WEB-INF so that cannot be requested directly.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.CharSequence` was added in Java 1.4, so if it can't find it, you're either running a **very** old Java, or you classpath is really messed up.

You should replace use of `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder`, which was added in Java 5. Use of `StringBuffer` is obsolete.

Quoting [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> As of release JDK 5, this class (*StringBuffer*) has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

Comment: i tried using StringBuilder but still got same error

Comment: Then your Tomcat installation seems to be corrupt.

Comment: my Apache Tomcat  Java classpath is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\bin\bootstrap.jar" and my index.jsp workes fine so why is it its breaking on redirect.